# How to get PN_src rpm package for a recipe from a core image recipe?

Tags: yocto, rpm, recipe

I need to have the sources (from PN-src package) of several recipes combined in one archive for specific image. Packages/recipes to be included would be specified in an core image recipe. I was considering making a task inside a core image recipe that would gather rpms of the selected packages and create an archive. The sources are in the located deploy/[TARGET]/*.rpm file. I could use the find command to locate the rpms but I would not want to write something that already exists (if this is the case ?). I was wondering if there is a way to know the location (TARGET) of a given recipe and it's version from the core image recipe? Or maybe there already exists a utility to copy the rpm-src package of the recipe?( utilities such as "fetch source package for recipe XXX", or "Get target/version of recipe XXX?"). I have tried to find such a functionality but I was unsuccessful until now.
Thanks for any hint on that.

Comment: Do you want to gather all rpm packages zipped into the final image ?

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM I wanted to gather some of the packages and create a separate zip package with the sources. . Packages would be specified in image recipe or config file.

Comment: "With the sources" you mean a zip file that collect all packages? Then you will install the zip and install the packages in the image live ? Clarify more with an example to help you with accurate response.

Comment: I would like to access the sources ( can be the rpm packages or the source files used to create the rpm packages) from the image recipe task. I will create a task that would collect sources from specified recipes and create an archive with the sources.
The reason for this is that we are building a full image using yocto for testing but the release only contains driver code, so I would like to be able to build an image and with  a command like: bitbake image-name -c create_release_package create an archive only containing the sources. @TalelBELHADJSALEM

Answer (score 1):

I will answer with my thoughts and what I understood from your comments, as comments section will not be enough to describe what I need to say.

I hope this can give you some hints.

If you have multiple recipes that you want to collect all packages together, or you want to specify some recipes and collect all source files used, then this can be a big work to do, let me give some ideas and then comment on this answer for more clarification:

If you want to collect only the final packages (rpm, ipk, deb), you can just develop a simple script that runs inside `tmp/deploy/<package_type>` and collect the packages. If you want to do it from inside Yocto, then you can use the `${WORKDIR}/oe-rootfs-repo` folder of your image recipe, it has all packages used to construct the rootfs. Maybe a `prepend` on `do_roofs` or other task that zip that full directory.

Now, if you want to collect all source files, this will get more harder, as sources vary: from git, local, svn, ftp, .. ?
You need to:

1. Loop through all recipes of your final image
2. Get `WORKDIR` of each one
3. Extract the sources unpacked there in a common place for all recipes